# Extend highlight from cell to row

Tags: vba, excel, formatting

This might be a very dumm question. I would like to point out that I am pretty new to VBA.
By looking in the internet here and there, I managed to create the following code, which I use to highlight all the cells containing a certain date. I would like now to tweak my code and extend the highlighnt to the rows of the cell containing a certain date, so that later I could easily copy and past them into a new tab.

```
Sub HighlightSpecificValue()

Dim fnd As String, FirstFound As String
Dim FoundDate As Range, rng As Range
Dim myRange As Range, LastCell As Range
Dim datetoFind As Date

'Value to be found
fnd = InputBox("Emter the date to be found", "Highlight")

'End Macro if Cancel Button is Clicked or no Text is Entered
  If fnd = vbNullString Then Exit Sub

'Convert String value to date format
 datetoFind = DateValue(fnd)

Set myRange = Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("E:E")
Set LastCell = myRange.Cells(myRange.Cells.Count)
Set FoundDate = myRange.Find(what:=datetoFind, _
                        after:=LastCell, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False, _
                        SearchFormat:=False)

'Test to see if anything was found
If Not FoundDate Is Nothing Then
FirstFound = FoundDate.Address
Else
GoTo NothingFound
End If

Set rng = FoundDate

'Loop until cycled through all unique finds
Do Until FoundDate Is Nothing
'Find next cell with fnd value
  Set FoundDate = myRange.FindNext(after:=FoundDate)

'Add found cell to rng range variable
  Set rng = Union(rng, FoundDate)

'Test to see if cycled through to first found cell
  If FoundDate.Address = FirstFound Then Exit Do

Loop

'Highlight Found cells yellow
rng.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)

'Report Out Message
MsgBox rng.Cells.Count & " cell(s) were found containing: " & fnd

Exit Sub

'Error Handler
NothingFound:
MsgBox "No cells containing: " & fnd & " were found in this worksheet"

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for your precious help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `EntireRow` method of the `Range` object.

```
rng.EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
```